# Haskell: All combinations between multiple Strings

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a list of Strings like this:

`["aesfa","gwopq","awefg"]`

I would want to get all possible combinations between those Strings, something like this:

`["aga","agw","age","agf", ... ,"sga","sgw", ... , "aqf","aqg"]`

The strings inside the list have all the same lenght, but could be any lenght, and the list could contain different numbers of strings

I tried the following list comprehensions:

-`getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:y | x <- z, y <- zs]`

This gives me, obviously, a list of the combinations between all the characters of the first string and the rest of the strings (not the characters).

-`getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:y | x <- z, y <-  getCombinations zs]`

This doesnt work if I dont do a pattern matching for the empy list, I did it like this:

`getCombinations [] = []`

but doing that make the function return always the empty list no matter what

weirdly enough, if I do:

-`getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:[y] | x <- z, y <- head zs]`

it gives me the combinations between the first two strings

I tried to extend that to get another String and I ended up with this:

`getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:[y]++[w] | x <- z, y <- (head zs), w <- (head(tail zs))]`

That gave me the combinations of the first three strings

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: I tried the following list comprehension 

`getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:y | x <- z, y <- zs]` but it gives me, obviously, a list of combinations between all the characters of the first string and the rest of the strings.

doing getCombinations (z:zs) = `[x:y | x <- z, y <-  getCombinations zs]` 

doesnt work and idk why. weirdly enough, if I do 

`getCombinations (z:zs) = `[x:[y] | x <- z, y <-  head zs]`

it gives me the combinations between the first two strings, but i dont know how to extend this to cover all possible strings

Comment: Hint: use recurse for `y <- ...`. You should also return something for the empty list.

Comment: Can you do it for a list that contains just one string, or even no strings? If so, perhaps given a result for N strings, you can try to extend it for N+1 strings. By the way, the condition that all strings are of the same length is not really needed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried with recursion and patter matching with the empty list, but it always gives me the empty list no matter what.

Comment: @DavidÁlvarezRojas: that is because your empty case is incorrect. Please [edit] the question and share your attempt.

Comment: "but it always gives me the empty list no matter what" Please [edit] your question and add all the failed attempts.

Comment: And if I do `getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:[y]++[w] | x <- z, y <- (head zs), w <- (head(tail zs))] ` it gives me all the combinations between the first three strings, but honestly I really don't know why it is behaving like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually quite close. The only problem is the case for the empty list:

```
getCombinations :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
getCombinations [] = []  -- ← empty list
getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:y | x <- z, y <- getCombinations zs]
```

If you here return the empty list, then that means that eventually `getCombinations zs` will return the empty list, and thus the list comprehension with that empty list... will also return an empty list.

If you have no strings, then basically there is *one* combination: the empty string, so you should return:

```
getCombinations :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
getCombinations [] = [[]]  -- singleton list with an empty string/list
getCombinations (z:zs) = [x:y | x <- z, y <- getCombinations zs]
```

You actually do not need to implement `getCombinations` yourself. Due to the `Monad` instance of list, `getCombinations` is a special case of [**`sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) :

```
Prelude> sequence ["aesfa","gwopq","awefg"]
["aga","agw","age","agf","agg","awa","aww","awe","awf","awg","aoa","aow","aoe","aof","aog","apa","apw","ape","apf","apg","aqa","aqw","aqe","aqf","aqg","ega","egw","ege","egf","egg","ewa","eww","ewe","ewf","ewg","eoa","eow","eoe","eof","eog","epa","epw","epe","epf","epg","eqa","eqw","eqe","eqf","eqg","sga","sgw","sge","sgf","sgg","swa","sww","swe","swf","swg","soa","sow","soe","sof","sog","spa","spw","spe","spf","spg","sqa","sqw","sqe","sqf","sqg","fga","fgw","fge","fgf","fgg","fwa","fww","fwe","fwf","fwg","foa","fow","foe","fof","fog","fpa","fpw","fpe","fpf","fpg","fqa","fqw","fqe","fqf","fqg","aga","agw","age","agf","agg","awa","aww","awe","awf","awg","aoa","aow","aoe","aof","aog","apa","apw","ape","apf","apg","aqa","aqw","aqe","aqf","aqg"]
```

Comment: Thank u, I did't thought that it was fault of the case of the empty list, that solved my problem. Also, I didn't knew that function existed, Im gonna use it then. Thank u again

Comment: See also [`choices`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:choices) which, unlike `sequence`, works sensibly even for lists with infinitely-long strings inside.